my varnish docker container not able to cache. 404 is what I get and cache miss and cache pass
I am running varnish as below:
 docker run -e VARNISH_BACKEND_HOST=pre.xplore.xircular.io -e VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT=9190 --tmpfs /var/lib/varnish/varnishd:exec -p 8080:80 varnish

My backend is nodejs and is deployed on the same host machine with port 9190 where varnish docker container is running alos running on port 8080.
after the setup, when accessing https://pre.xplore.xircular.io , I don't see anyhting and see an error. but when I comment out the proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; then I get back the website UI.
if I am accessing http://pre.xplore.xircular.io, I get cache miss
vcl file:
backend default {
    .host = "pre.xplore.xircular.io";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
}

sub vcl_deliver {
}

LOGS:
varnishlog -g request
*   << Request  >> 9084183   
-   Begin          req 9084182 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1732861423.090362 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1732861423.090362 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       106.51.90.72 39672 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: pre.xplore.xircular.io:8085
-   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
-   ReqHeader      DNT: 1
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,or-IN;q=0.8,or;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: consent-policy=%7B%22ess%22%3A1%2C%22func%22%3A1%2C%22anl%22%3A1%2C%22adv%22%3A1%2C%22dt3%22%3A1%2C%22ts%22%3A28582028%7D; _ga=GA1.1.825846258.1714921730; _ga_XM155BLZ4M=GS1.1.1722245307.31.1.1722245499.0.0.0; _clck=gprvcn%7C2%7Cfra%7C0%7C1625; _
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 106.51.90.72
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     pass
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       PASS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 9084184 pass
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1732861423.092268 0.001906 0.001906
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     301
-   RespReason     Moved Permanently
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2024 06:23:43 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 178
-   RespHeader     Location: https://pre.xplore.xircular.io/
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 9084183
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1732861423.092284 0.001921 0.000015
-   Filters        
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1732861423.092357 0.001995 0.000073
-   ReqAcct        957 0 957 275 178 453
-   End            
**  << BeReq    >> 9084184   
--  Begin          bereq 9084183 pass
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1732861423.090848 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    Host: pre.xplore.xircular.io:8085
--  BereqHeader    DNT: 1
--  BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,or-IN;q=0.8,or;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
--  BereqHeader    Cookie: consent-policy=%7B%22ess%22%3A1%2C%22func%22%3A1%2C%22anl%22%3A1%2C%22adv%22%3A1%2C%22dt3%22%3A1%2C%22ts%22%3A28582028%7D; _ga=GA1.1.825846258.1714921730; _ga_XM155BLZ4M=GS1.1.1722245307.31.1.1722245499.0.0.0; _clck=gprvcn%7C2%7Cfra%7C0%7C1625; _
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 106.51.90.72
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 9084184
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  BackendOpen    27 default 139.5.190.56 80 139.5.190.56 60056
--  BackendStart   139.5.190.56 80
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1732861423.091408 0.000560 0.000560
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1732861423.091687 0.000839 0.000279
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   301
--  BerespReason   Moved Permanently
--  BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
--  BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2024 06:23:43 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html
--  BerespHeader   Content-Length: 178
--  BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
--  BerespHeader   Location: https://pre.xplore.xircular.io/
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Filters        
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Fetch_Body     3 length stream
--  BackendReuse   27 default
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1732861423.092333 0.001485 0.000646
--  Length         178
--  BereqAcct      984 0 984 215 178 393
--  End            

*   << Request  >> 16813403  
-   Begin          req 16813402 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1732861461.981903 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1732861461.981903 0.000000 0.000000
-   HttpGarbage    "%16%03%01%06%ff%01%00"
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     400
-   RespReason     Bad Request
-   ReqAcct        1796 0 1796 28 0 28
-   End 

My nginx configuration:
upstream xplore_server {
    server localhost:9190;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name pre.xplore.xircular.io;

    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pre.xplore.xircular.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pre.xplore.xircular.io/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    root /var/www/xplore/Divikit-campaigns;
   
    location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8085;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

   
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  location /campaign/d9ab0589-f2fe-4543-b643-787da711b0b8 {
    return 301 https://appclip.apple.com/id?p=com.xircular.XplorePromote.Clip&campaignId=6700c20b-5e48-4e23-927c-930bc8e8db20;
   }


   location /.well-known/assetlinks.json {
    root /var/www/xplore; # Path to your file
    default_type application/json; 
    add_header Content-Type application/json; 
    try_files $uri =404; 
   }
  location /apple-app-site-association {
    alias /var/www/xplore/.well-known/apple-app-site-association;
    default_type application/json; 
    add_header Content-Type application/json; 
    try_files $uri =404;  
   }

 location /.well-known/apple-app-site-association {
    alias /var/www/xplore/.well-known/apple-app-site-association;
    default_type application/json; 
    add_header Content-Type application/json;  
    try_files $uri =404; 
   }

    location /socket.io/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://xplore_server/socket.io/;
        proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_read_timeout 86400;
      proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
      proxy_send_timeout 7d;
   }

    location /api/v1/ {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,X-Auth-Token' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH' always;

        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_pass http://xplore_server/;
        

        access_log /var/log/nginx/xplore-v1.log log_bodydata2;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,X-Auth-Token' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pre.xplore.xircular.io;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

I would like to cache the backend data and whenever a user accesses my website https:pre.xplore.xircualr.io,should reciieve the responses afster as part of the varnish caching.

I think there are some formatting problems here that make things confusing to read that you may want to address. Aside from that, I'm unclear on the relationship between nginx and varnish: is it client -> nginx -> varnish -> backend, or is it client - > varnish -> nginx -> backend?  Does varnish successfully handle the request if you use curl to make requests directly to varnish?

I agree with @larsks that the formatting of the output should be improved. This will make it easier to understand. The varnishlog output is really important here, so please ensure you share both the request & backend request transaction. right now you only shared the regular request. I'd like to see what's going on on the backend side, so please don't just add -c to the varnishlog output, as it will only output the client-side transaction.

Please also add the VCL file to your question. The correlation between the full varnishlog output (client & backend transaction) and the VCL, will help us understand what's going on.

Hi @ThijsFeryn I have added the vcl file config and the full logs. I am not able to format the nginx code here.

Based on the logs and your VCL file, I can conclude that there are 2 things going on in your setup:

Cache bypassing because of cookies
HTTP to HTTPS redirection

Let's go into detail.
1. Cache bypassing because of cookies
Varnish built-in VCL behavior states that incoming requests containing a Cookie or Authorization header cannot be served from the cache, because they imply a level of personalization.
The logs show that you have the following Cookie header set:
Cookie: consent-policy=%7B%22ess%22%3A1%2C%22func%22%3A1%2C%22anl%22%3A1%2C%22adv%22%3A1%2C%22dt3%22%3A1%2C%22ts%22%3A28582028%7D; _ga=GA1.1.825846258.1714921730; _ga_XM155BLZ4M=GS1.1.1722245307.31.1.1722245499.0.0.0; _clck=gprvcn%7C2%7Cfra%7C0%7C1625; _

I'm not sure whether any of these cookies are used by the backend application, or if all of them are processed by frontend Javascript.
My advice is to remove every cookie you don't need on the backend. The simplest way of doing this is by defining a whitelist of cookies you need.
Here's some example VCL to achieve that:
vcl 4.1;

import cookie;

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.cookie) {
        cookie.parse(req.http.cookie);
        cookie.keep("session,lang");
        set req.http.cookie = cookie.get_string();

        if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
            unset req.http.cookie;
        }
    }
}

In this hypothetical case, we are removing all tracking & frontend cookies. We only keep the cookies named session and lang. If these cookies are set, the cache is still bypassed, and rightfully so.
If these cookies are not set, Varnish can cache the page.
2. HTTP to HTTPS redirection
Varnish Cache, to open source version of Varnish, doesn't offer native TLS support. That means you have to terminate TLS using a TLS proxy, and for Varnish any incoming and outgoing request is over plain HTTP.
Varnish can detect whether the incoming connection was a terminated TLS connection though.
This through the X-Forwarded-Proto header that announces the initial protocol that was used. If the TLS proxy doesn't set that header, Varnish can set it itself by assigning a separate listening port for TLS-terminated traffic. All traffic on that port is triggered by https:// URLs.
Here's some example VCL code to set the X-Forwarded-Proto header if it wasn't set by the TLS proxy:
sub vcl_recv {
    if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        if(std.port(server.ip) == 443 || std.port(server.ip) == 8443) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
        }
    }
}

In this case traffic on Varnish listening port 443 or 8443 is for HTTPS traffic, so we set the X-Forwarded-Proto header accordingly. If the request comes in on port 80 or another port, it's plain HTTP.
However, your Nginx configuration has no X-Forwarded-Proto awareness either. All requests that Varnish sends to the Nginx backend, will be redirected to the HTTPS equivalent.
But since Varnish cannot process TLS directly, you can end up in an infinite loop.
Solving the redirection problem
There are 2 ways to solve the redirection problem:

Build in X-Forwarded-Proto awareness in your Nginx configuration
Upgrade to the commercial version of Varnish and use the native end-to-end TLS capabilities that are supported by this product

Fixing your Nginx config
While I'm not an Nginx expert, I can advise you to move the Nginx logic from your 443 vhost to your 80 vhost.
The only thing your 443 vhost should do, is proxy HTTPS content to Varnish.
Your HTTP to HTTPS redirection logic can remain inside the port 80 vhost, but please ensure it is only triggered if the X-Forwarded-Proto value is not https.
Use Varnish Enterprise
If you prefer to have end-to-end TLS support, and secure incoming and outgoing traffic from Varnish over TLS, you can upgrade to Varnish Enterprise.
Varnish Enterprise offers native client TLS support, where Varnish could listen both on ports 80 & 443 and where Varnish is capable of doing the HTTP to HTTPS redirection itself.
Varnish Enterprise also offers backend TLS support, where requests from Varnish to the backend are also encrypted through TLS.
Here's a VCL example of how backend TLS can be enabled:
backend default {
    .host = "pre.xplore.xircular.io";
    .port = "443";
    .ssl = 1;
}

It's simply a matter of setting the backend port to 443 and to enable the ssl property.
By using this backend TLS feature, you would not end up on the port 80 vhost of your Nginx configuration, and benefit from end-to-end TLS encryption.
